# Function with return type based on a protected base class method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to let the return type of `doSomeMethod()` be the same as the `operator()` in the base class but if it's declared as protected the compiler rejects the code with `error: no type named 'type' in 'std::result_of'`. It works if it's public but i wonder if I could get it working for the protected case too since.

Here is simple code reproducing the error.

```
#include <type_traits>

class base
{
protected:
    int operator()(){return 1;};
};

class child : private base
{
    auto static doSomeMethod()
            -> typename std::result_of<base()>::type
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

EDIT:

Ok thanks Kerrek SB and Dietmar Kühlr for your solutions and explanations. After playing around with it I found this solution that is more readable and works (at least in my real case where `child` is template class and `base` one of its template parameters) more reliable.
But it seems that it goes a bit against your explanations. Or is it just the way `std::result_of<>` is broken in this case?

```
#include <type_traits>

class base
{
protected:
    double operator()(){ return 1; };
    int operator()(int i){ return i; };
};

class child : private base 
{
  public:
    auto operator()()
      -> decltype(base::operator()()) 
    {
        return base::operator()();
    }

  auto operator()(int i)
      -> decltype(base::operator()(std::declval<int>())) 
    {
         return base::operator()(i);
    }
};
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

If your code is literally this, then you can exploit the fact that the protected `operator()` from `base` is also available in `child`, and use a simple trait:

```
template <typename> struct memfn_result;

template <typename C, typename R, typename ...Args>
struct memfn_result<R (C::*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = R;
};

class base
{
protected:
    int operator()(){ return 1; };
};

class child : private base
{
    memfn_result<decltype(&child::operator())>::type a;    // "a" is an "int"
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `base::operator()()` is `protected` and you are using it on an object of type `base` rather than an object of type `child` you clearly can't access the member! You need to access the function call operator using an object of type `child`. Sadly, `child` is incomplete in the context where you are trying to access it, i.e., you need to an indirection:

```
class child
    : private base {
    auto static doSomeMethod()
        -> decltype((std::declval<base>().*(&child::operator()))()) {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: I think the `&` in `base&` is unnecessary.

Comment: @KerrekSB: yes, it seems to be unnecessary. I used it to avoid potential issues with non-existing copy constructor but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: There's no copy involved. The return type is always a reference, so this is always an lvalue (though unevaluated, of course).

Comment: @KerrekSB Per C++11 §20.2.4/1 `declval` is declared `template <class T> typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;`, so `decltype(std::declval<base>())` is `base&&`. It makes no difference in this case, but would if `base::operator()` was declared with an lvalue ref-qualifier.

Comment: @Casey: Ah, thanks - I was under the impression the return type always had an lvalue reference added. Makes sense, though.